# How to get the previous paragraph's style in VSTO word 2010 using c# word addin?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

my requirement is apply the styles to paragraph in document, I apply some styles to some paragraph based on regex condition, some paragraphs is more difficult to assign styles, I want to get the apply the style depends on previous paragraph styles

Comment: Please Tell your Question Clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I try This based on your Question.

```
word.Document myDocx = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            string prevParaStyle = string.Empty;
            string nextParaStyle = string.Empty;
            string curParaStyle = string.Empty;
            foreach (word.Paragraph eachPara in myDocx.Paragraphs)
            {
                if (eachPara.Previous(1) != null)
                    prevParaStyle = ((word.Style)eachPara.Previous(1).get_Style()).NameLocal;
                if(eachPara.Next(1)!=null)
                    nextParaStyle = ((word.Style)eachPara.Next(1).get_Style()).NameLocal;
                    curParaStyle = ((word.Style)eachPara.get_Style()).NameLocal;
            }
```